# Having+verb3 in English

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

i have gone through few documents in google about ‘having+verb3’ and came to know below thing.

1. ‘Having done’ —> can be said as ‘After doing’
2. Having finished our work, we went home.

We could also say After –ing.

After finishing our work, we went home.

so is that correct or any other opinions?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are generally equivalent, although there is a subtle difference.

> Having finished our work, we went home.

This sentence emphasizes that they went home because there was no reason to remain after finishing the work.

> After finishing our work, we went home.

This sentence emphasizes that they did not go home until the work was finished.